# Populate HTML forms in WebView

Tags: nativescript

I have a NativeScript-5 app (TypeScript flavor) with a simple page like this:

```
<Page class="page">
   <StackLayout>
      <WebView id="webView" loaded="onWebViewLoaded" src="http://google.com" />
   </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

After loading the web page (onWebViewLoded()), I would like my app to populate certain HTML fields (access by id or name) and finally post the surrounding HTML form. Can this be done at all?

I know that there is a [Nativescript-WebView-Interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface) plugin, but it requires me to embed a script in the loaded page (and I can't do this, because I don't own the page I am loading). So I assume I need another approach.

If anybody has a solution that works at least on Android, that would be great. Thanks guys!

**Update**:
In order to avoid misunderstandings: Submitting the page is optional. The important part is to load a web page and auto-fill some values that my app already knows (so the user does not have to enter these values in the HTML form himself).

Comment: It sounds like you should call an API instead of loading up a webpage just to fill a form and auto-post. Are you sure you want to do it the way you have described?

Comment: Well, unfortunately there is no API. So yes, I need to load a certain web page (it's NOT Google - this was just an example) and then populate 2-3 fields and submit.

Comment: You can construct the message a post it yourself without having to load up a page, though. It may not be a well-documented API, but if they have a form that posts values, it's (almost certainly) there.

Comment: @Ian, thank you. It's very nice of you to think of a totally different approach. But in this case I need "my way" in all different kinds of scenarios. So I really need a way to load and show a web page with auto-populated values. In most cases, my users will submit the web form themselves by taping on an HTML button. So, in this case, it's not about calling an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may easily execute JavaScript in the webpage context in Android.

```
export function onLoadFinished(args: EventData) {
    const webView = (<WebView>args.object).nativeView;

    if (isAndroid) {
        // Make sure the element index is valid
        const javaScript = `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value = "It works!"`;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.evaluateJavascript(javaScript, null);
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(`javascript:${javaScript}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=veRbTe)

It's also possible with iOS, but you may have to override / extend the existing {N} WebView inject JavaScript upon creating native view.

Comment: Excellent, Manoj. You are the best helper when it comes to NativeScript! To be honest I figured out the same solution late last night - but was too tired to post it. Wanted to do it right now. So, thank you so much!

Comment: I see you are doing freelance works as well. I might have something now and then. How could I get in touch with you? If you are interested, you can reach me via stackoverflow@softwarea.de.