# Flutter - Populate HTML forms in WebView

Tags: flutter

I would like to develop an app using Flutter, which will help user to autofill in the webpage (the data is already stored in app.

My app will have a simple webview to load the web page. And thenＩwould like to populate the webpage data (e.g. name, ID card no., etc) which is already stored in my application. If possible, i would also like to submit the web page on behalf of the user but it is not a must.

I have searched the web. Below is the closest thing that I have read. However, it is in Android but my preference is to do this in Flutter.

[Populate HTML forms in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149388/populate-html-forms-in-webview)

It would be grateful if you could give me some direction, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible. Check out these stackoverflow resources

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67688317/11212287

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350069/11212287

Comment: thanks a lot AkshayDoshi, I will have a look on the two links that you provided.